# How to make a wrapper that simplifies requests with tornado AsyncHTTPClient?

Tags: python, generator, tornado, yield

I want to write a simple function that releases me from repeatedly creating `AsyncHTTPClient` and `HTTPRequest` and doing `client.fetch`.

Now I came up with the following code:

```
def async_fetch(url, method='GET', headers={}, body=None):
    '''Fetch an HTTP resource asynchronously
       using `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient`
    '''

    if isinstance(body, dict):
        body = urlencode(body)

    request = HTTPRequest(url, method=method, headers=headers, body=body)
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield client.fetch(request)
    return response.body
```

Obviously this will not work. It returns a generator itself and I don't know how to apply it in a RequestHandler.

I can merely return `client.fetch(client)`, which is a task, and yield this task in the handler, but I want the processing of the response wrapped out as well.

Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [tornado >=3](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) you may create custom coroutine that returns something using [gen.Return](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html?highlight=gen#tornado.gen.Return):

```
@gen.coroutine
def async_fetch(url, method='GET', headers={}, body=None):
    async_http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_request = HTTPRequest(url, method=method, headers=headers, body=body)
    http_response = yield client.fetch(http_request)
    raise gen.Return(http_response)  # That's how return looks in tornado

class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get():
        ...
        response = yield async_fetch('http://example.org')
        ...
```

In tornado 2.x a more wordly approach is required:

```
@gen.engine
def async_fetch(url, method='GET', headers={}, body=None, callback=None):
    async_http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_request = HTTPRequest(url, method=method, headers=headers, body=body)
    http_response = yield client.fetch(http_request)
    if callback:
        callback(http_response)

class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    @web.asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get():
        ...
        response = yield gen.Task(async_fetch, 'http://example.org')
        ...
```

You may go even further and return an instance of `gen.Task` from `async_fetch`.

**Update**
Both `gen.coroutine` and `gen.Return` are valuable. `gen.coroutine` allows to call one coroutine from another (`yield client.fetch(..)`). `gen.Return` allows to return some value from generator. Both were introduced to overcome Python <3.4 limitations -- the lack of `yield from` construction.

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking this out. Didn't expect it to be so simple. At the same time I remembered in the document it mentioned that gen.Return is the same as return in Python posterior to 3.3. So I guess the key is not gen.Return but the coroutine decorator?